# notepad++: create regular expression to change color of comment following comment

Tags: javascript, regex, comments, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I know that every syntax highlight in notepad++ is based on regular expressions configured for the current language, but where do notepad++ stores the files relative to these regexes?

In my case, I want to highlight javascript **comments that are placed following (or inside, using double slashes, if you prefer) comments** in a different way of standard comments, like that:

```
product(); //just a comment about what is being made on the execution part of the line
//sum(); //comment formatted the same way as the executional part, which is also commented
```

That is because I want to distinguish these comments from commented execution code. The commented execution line is '//sum();' in this case, as '//comment...' is the comment that was commented and is following the first comment. Both are gray, but I want notepad++ to use another color to show everything that is after the second pair of slashes.

Anybody can also help me in building this regex?

Comment: JavaScript comments cannot be nested, so, problem solved.

Comment: they have a meaning for the developer, that is why I want to highlight them in another way, no matter if javascript won't interpret them. Notepad++ can (I think) if it has the correct regex

Comment: What you are showing is not a "comment inside of a comment". It is simply two comments in a row.

Comment: Because a comment inside a comment would be /* blabla /* comment inside comment*/ blabla*/, right? This regex is not important for me, only the '//comment //another comment', which, yes, may be regarded as inlining comments. Anyway, for the regex I want, the name won't matter, only the pattern and the file where I need to store it.